# Como hacer Post con Symfony 4

Tags: php, symfony4

Implementando el siguiente metodo post en symfony 4, funciona bien con GET pero falla con POST

```
/**
 * @Rest\Post(path="/books")
 * @Rest\View(serializerGroups={"book"}, serializerEnableMaxDepthChecks=true)
 */
public function postAction(Request $request) {
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $book = new Book();
    $form = $this->createForm(BookFormType::class, $book);
    $form->handleRequest($request);
    
    if($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()){
        $em->persist($book);
        $em->flush();
        return $book;
    }
    return $form;
}
```

Me da el siguiente error

```
"code": 500,
"message": "Cannot autowire argument $request of \"App\\Controller\\Api\\BooksController::postAction()\": 
it references class \"symfony\\Component\\HttpFoundation\\Request\" but no such service exists."
```

Estas son mis referencias en el controller

```
use App\Entity\Book;
use App\Form\Type\BookFormType;
use App\Repository\BookRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use FOS\RestBundle\Controller\AbstractFOSRestController;
use FOS\RestBundle\Controller\Annotations as Rest;
use symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
```

Answer (score 0):

Logre solucionarlo de la siguiente manera, había cometido un error de sintaxis en un  namespace

```
use symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
```

Lo reemplace de la siguiente manera

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
```

Y se corrigio el error